# Zooming the interval arround $0.333\cdots $, whats wrong?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm trying to zoom the interval arround $0.333\cdots$ with:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[Table[{n, Sum[3/10^x, {x, n}]}, {n, 1, 20, 1}], 
  Mesh -> All, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {(Sum[3/10^t, {t, g}] - 1/10^g), (Sum[3/10^t, {t, g}] + 1/
       10^g)}}], {g, 2, 20, 0.001}]
```

I know that I can use the interval `(Sum[3/10^t, {t, g}] - 1/10^g), (Sum[3/10^t, {t, g}] + 1/10^g)` because I've evaluated this:

```
Table[N[Sum[3/10^t, {t, n}] - 1/10^n, n], {n, 2, 10}]
```

Which yields:

```
(* {0.32, 0.332, 0.3332, 0.33332, 0.333332, 0.3333332, 0.33333332, 0.333333332, 0.3333333332} *)
```

And:

```
Table[N[Sum[3/10^t, {t, n}] + 1/10^n, n], {n, 2, 10}]
```

which yields:

```
(* {0.34, 0.334, 0.3334, 0.33334, 0.333334, 0.3333334, 0.33333334, 0.333333334, 0.3333333334} *)
```

But something weird is happening and the plot is jumping in a weird way. I have no clue of what's going on.

Comment: Please don't use backticks + quote for code... use the markdown for code, which is indentation by 4 spaces. See the [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that PlotRange is using $MachinePrecision:

```
GraphicsGrid@Partition[Table[
   prec = g;
   ListLinePlot[Table[{n, Sum[3/10^x, {x, n}]}, {n, 20}], Mesh -> All,
                PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {N[1/3 - 1/10^prec, prec], 
                             N[1/3 + 1/10^prec, prec]}}, 
                PlotLabel -> "Precision = " <> ToString@g ], 
   {g, 4, Floor@$MachinePrecision, 1}], 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if it is what you wanted. as I am was exactly sure. This only zooms in the y scale. You can make it also zoom in the x-scale to get closer look.

```
Manipulate[
 If[low >= high, low = high - 1];
 If[high <= low, high = low + 1];

 ListLinePlot[tbl, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {{0, 23}, {tbl[[low, 2]], tbl[[high, 2]]}},
  ImagePadding -> 50, ImageSize -> 400, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
 ,
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{low, 1, "lower limit?"}, 1, 19, 1}], Dynamic@low},
   {Control[{{high, 4, "upper limit?"}, 2, 20, 1}], Dynamic@high}
   }],
 SynchronousUpdating -> True,
 Initialization :>
  (
   tbl = Table[{n, Sum[3/10^x, {x, n}]}, {n, 1, 20, 1}];
   )
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is that the function you are using for the plot range (`Sum[3/10^t, {t, g}] + 1/ 10^g`) is not continuous. The sum adds a new term only when `g` crosses an integer boundary. Observe:

```
ListPlot[Table[(Sum[3/10^t, {t, g}] - 1/10^g), {g, 2.5, 3.5, 0.001}]]
```

If you use the analytic version of the sum:

```
(Sum[3/10^t, {t, g}] - 1/10^g) //FullSimplify
```

$\frac{10^{-g}}{3}(-4 + 10^g)$

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[Table[{n, Sum[3/10^x, {x, n}]}, {n, 1, 20, 1}], 
Mesh -> All, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {1/3 10^-g (-4 + 10^g), 
 1/3 10^-g (2 + 10^g)}}], {g, 2, 20, 0.1}]
```

works until `g` is about 14, which I think is when the limits of machine precision.